# tab overflow exception in my brain - strategies and ideas for dealing with too many tabs in web browser

Tags: user-interface, browser

A common problem I find myself dealing with is having way too many tabs in my browser.  Part of this I know is just trying to do too many things at once.  I tell myself to focus focus on one task at a time and try to close tabs I'm not using.  Nevertheless, I still often find myself with over 20 tabs open at a time, just because apps that I use in the course of the day that I don't want to keep opening and closing and have them be in different positions.

I have not seen any great ways in either Chrome or Firefox to deal with tab overload. I had a couple ideas of possible UI enhancements to deal with this.  I know there's a couple of tab grouping/organization extensions for Firefox and Chrome, but I've tried most of them and haven't found them all that helpful.  One feature that would be nice is if it automatically grouped tabs by category/domain (so for example all my finance-related websites automatically open in the same group).

That said, how do you manage large number of tabs, and do you have any ideas of browser enhancements for dealing this this?

(Another pet-peeve of mine is that Chrome doesn't have MRU (most recently used tab switching), which is a huge pain for me when I'm working with two pages and having to switch back and forth between them. But that's sort of a different topic)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/tabcandy/
Tab candy in firefox 4 beta

http://tabsugar.com/
same thing for chrome

I've had your exact problem. With tab candy I've had up to ~90 tabs open at once with no issues at all, except memory use :)

Answer (score 0):

I just use a combinatioin of tabs and windows, with each window containing a logical grouping of tabs.  In both FF and Chrome, I can drag tabs between windows to reorgaize them as desired.  Also, on Linux or OS X, you can use multiple workspaces, each with one or more browser windows.  I dunno -- maybe Windows 7 has workspaces too now?